# How to use Vertex Array Objects in OpenGL ES 2

Tags: java, android, opengl-es-2.0

I am trying to use OpenGL ES and java for android and I noticed that there are no methods for Vertex Array Objects in the GLES20 class. Is it possible to use Vertex Array Objects at all with GLES20? Or do I have to try something else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Android, you can use Vertex Array Object starting with Opengl ES 3.0.

In GLES20 you can work only with VBO.

- http://developer.android.com/reference/android/opengl/GLES30.html#glBindVertexArray(int)
- http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/glutils/VertexBufferObjectWithVAO.html
- http://blog.linderdaum.com/2013/10/19/vao/

Comment: Thank you. I was hoping this wasn't the case, but it appears that it is.